# Client side Validation - Android

Tags: android

Can we do client side validation in android native app? 
i.e. in XML page itself can we check whether field is empty, only numeric for phone number, etc

Comment: In XML, no. In Java, yes. But it's all still client-side.

Comment: Will it not effect performance of app? For ex: in J2EE, jsp or javascript validation happens much quicker compared to validation in java class.

Comment: Checking if a field is empty? You'd have to do it thousands of times per second to notice *any* performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the user to enter only numeric fields in textBox by addding type (in xml) as

```
android:inputType="number"
```

so you don't need to validate it for numbers. But yes for checking empty fileds probably you need to check in java code by comparing the length of your textBox values.

Comment: Thanks Naresh, other than this what else can we check in xml itself? Plz share if u have any resource link.

Comment: Glad to help you, this link explains all the `inputType` for editBox : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType